# Weighted text search with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, text-search

I have a MongoDB Atlas cluster that I reach from a node.js server.

I implemented a text search where I take an input from the user, let's say "*rainbow*", and create a string like that: "*rai rain rainb rainbo rainbow*".
Then use that string to do a text search on indexed fields and sort the results by score.
That's the code I use to search over the database:

```js
await myCollection.createIndex({ Description: 'text' });

const searchResult = await myCollection.find(
  { $text: { $search: rainbowString } },
  { projection: { Description: 1, Price: 1, score: { $meta: 'textScore' } } }
).sort({ score: { $meta: 'textScore' } }).limit(20);

// where rainbowString is the string I spoke about earlier
```

Now I would like to make some improvements. For example, a "*rainbows*" string in my database is not going to be found. (In general misspelled words or abbreviations are not going to find a match. By writing "*pat*" you will not find neither "*path*" nor "*pet*").

I could make the algorithm add an "*s*" at the end of every word typed by the user (or any letter in any place), ending up with this string "*rai rain rainb rainbo rainbow rainbows*". However in this way "*rainbows*" would score higher than "*rainbow*" (which is what the user originally typed).

I guess I could add an extra copy of every word typed by the user to make my own weighted search: "*rainbow rai rain rainb rainbo rainbow rainbows*". However searching twice the same word is a waste of resources. Imagine if you want to use like five different weights (with each weight assigned to a group of words).

So my question is: is there a way I can tell mongo that I want to look for "*rainbow*" with a weight of say 4 and for each of the words in the string: "*rai rain rainb rainbo rainbows*" with a weight of 1?

Comment: If you want to save a lot of time, look at search engines such as algolia or typesense or lucene or solr. Algolia actually creates another copy of the index to achieve that although you could play around with synonyms. Doing what you describe in mongodb shall lead you to a very long and winding rabbit hole probably with no end.  They have some good resources here as well https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCiuXt-f2Faan4Es37nADUdQ

Comment: A more relevant link https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/sending-and-managing-data/manage-your-indices/#replicating-an-index  Typesense doesn't require you to make copies so you can look at how they do it.

Comment: @Gandalf thanks for the resources, I'll check these search engines.